# Setting value to true or false based on function execution

Tags: javascript

I've docking and undocking feature in my application.

When user undocks the window and dock back in, both `function1` and `function2` will be executed.

If user closed the undock window(pop-up window) only `function2` will be executed.

Issue is, I want to set the value to true if the function1 executes. i can't change the order of the functions.

How do i do it? Please help

```
function1(){
 this.Watch.setValue(true);
}

function2(){
this.Watch.setValue(false);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the minimum amount of code required to test for your undesired behavior and then we can help to come up with a solution.

Comment: Why not use a variable and set its value when function1 executes as true. I assume there must be some event where you are calling these methods from, so before calling this false the value of variable which you will later set as true in function1.

Comment: why dont using var?

Answer (score 0):

hope this `bind` function may help, click run to see the result, use the new functions will update value

```js
const [dock, undock, getValue] = bind(oldDock, oldUndock, false)

console.log(getValue())
dock()
console.log(getValue())
undock()
console.log(getValue())


function bind(toTrue, toFalse, initValue) {
  let val = initValue
  return [
    (...args) => {
      val = true
      toTrue(...args)
    },
    (...args) => {
      val = false
      toFalse(...args)
    },
    () => val,
  ]
}

function oldDock() {
  console.log('dock')
}

function oldUndock() {
  console.log('undock')
}
```